# Is it possible to program an Arduino from another embedded device?

Tags: arduino, embedded, upgrade

I am currently working on a system (home projects - finally got the time yay!) and i am wondering whether it would be possible to program an arduino from a pic32? the system currently has both and given the pic32 proc has an SD card attached, i figured i could use the platform potentially to program all the other systems if there was new firmware deployed onto the SD card..
just wondered if it was possible? there doesnt seem to be anything online but maybe im googling the wrong thing? i suppose the pic32 would be acting as an ISP?
Thanks in advance..
Chris

Comment: Your problem finding resources on line probably stem from you looking for *Arduino* material instead of *Atmel* material.  The details for ISP in AVR are fully documented [here](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc0943.pdf).

Comment: @Clifford Thanks for the link, i shall investigate further, you are quite right that i was being too specific perhaps in terms of product. Also as mentioned below, there seems to be some variation on what each board does etc where as the Atmel route seems less variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure, why not, it is just spi.  I think just out of convenience (of something with spi on it or trivial to bit bang) I use another microcontroller to program my avr (an msp430 or mbed which program easily over usb).  avrs docs are pretty good on the protocol.  you can use the serial bootloader as well, but that gets into a larger number of combinations of which arduino, what speed the uart is, exactly how and you have to tickle the dtr (reset), seemed like when I was still messing with that each arduino board type was different.  Where with the isp interface excluding xmega, there are chip to chip differences as far as the identification number, etc but easier come up with something more generic.  And the nice thing about that spi interface is the processor is in reset so you are not relying on there being a bootloader, what version of the bootloader, or a chip with a flash that is for some reason causing a hang, etc.  you should generally get the same programming experience independent as to what was programmed before.

Comment: @Jon Thanks for that ISP link, its verry interesting! it backs up what Mr. dwelch (i cant use more than one @ reference..:( )was saying in terms of it being SPI functions (which makes it very managable in terms of number of pins required too from the main proc. I assume this will override/blank the normal bootloader being held on the arduino? unless the bin/hex output by the compiler is set to the right memory spaces already?

Comment: I think there are separate flashes or separately accessed flash banks for the bootloader and the application.  Not sure though you might be right, lots of different vendor data bouncing around in my head, not everyone protects the bootloader flash with separate access....

Comment: it is bad form to put links in answers at SO so I didnt, comments is okay, you will need the specific chips datasheet for some of the details, as well as the generic protocol documents if they have them.  again atmel is pretty good at documenting things.  there was one item or chunk of info that was tricky to find, avrdude has it in a header file or something, I eventually found it, would have to re-research to figure out what that info was.

Comment: https://github.com/dwelch67  avr_samples has some very simple msp430 and mbed code, no doubt I also used the raspberry pi so maybe that is in the raspberry pi directory not sure.  the xmega is a different beast, still definitely doable but the timing is critical, and I dont think it was actually spi, non-xmega is the easy one, supporting a large number of chips like avrdude you need a table of info, how much flash depending on the part you find, etc.

Comment: @dwelch Thanks for the help and the github repo, ill dig into it as soon as i get a mo, your help is very much appreciated! (as is everyone elses..)